# Why absolute paths in Django settings

Tags: django, path, settings

I noticed in Django's settings file, there was a comment telling the user to use absolute paths for the template directories. Give that it would make it more portable to use relative paths, why is this?

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )
```

Comment: If i were to guess, it is more expensive for relative paths to be evaluated for every request, than absolute path. Actually you would never do `C:/www/...` - you would do something like `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` and use this setting as prefix for the rest of the path.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt... check the documentation. According to the [Django Docs](https://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter04.html),

> ◾It’s simplest to use absolute paths (i.e., directory paths that start at the root of the filesystem). If you want to be a bit more flexible and decoupled, though, you can take advantage of the fact that Django settings files are just Python code by constructing the contents of TEMPLATE_DIRS dynamically.

So to ensure portability while also ensuring the use of absolute paths, you generate the path dynamically as to avoid going down the awful road of hard-coded paths. As stated by @karthikr in his comment you can do something like,

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

where `'templates'` is a directory within your project that contains your various html templates.

Comment: I did check the documentation, its not in there. The Django book you are linking to even says that it (the book) is out of date.

Comment: @wobbily_col I just updated the link to the Django documentation and it says the same quote that I had from the older version. Your question concerning the increase in portability using relative paths is answered by the fact that since the absolute path can be defined dynamically using Python there is no loss in portability when using absolute paths.